# IOS6: Size of View in Landscape

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios6

just updated to IOS SDK 6 and now I'm confused. Tried to find a solution but I failed.

1. Created a new "Single View iPad APP" (I have an iPad 3) in xcode
2. Disabled Portrait & Upside-Down interface orientations in TARGETS->Summary
3. Set simulated metrics "orientation" to "Landscape"
4. Added following lines of code into the view controller file:

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
   }

   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   }

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
   }

   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
       NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
   }
   ```
5. Run APP

My output is: **2012-10-09 18:18:40.149 TestApp[6165:907] {{20, 0}, {748, 1024}}**
Does anybody know why the frame is not **... {{0, 20}, {1024, 748}}** as I would expect? Maybe I missed something!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you missed anything, but if you wrap your view controller with a `UINavigationController`, the frame will be set as expected.

NB: With the iOS 6 SDK, you can no longer combine any of the UIInterfaceOrientation constants as a mask. So you need:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

That doesn't explain the issue, though, since preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is not called when a view controller is the root controller of a `UIWindow`.